# ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified

Tags: sql, oracle

The following query returns

```
select to_char( trunc(sysdate) - numtoyminterval(level - 1, 'month'), 'mon-yy') as month from dual connect by level <= 12
```

last 12 months according to today's date(i.e. 2-Jan-18).

[image]

Say if today's date is 29-DEC-17 it gives oracle sql error: 
**ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified**
(since on subtracting there would be a date in the result as **'29-FEB-17'** which is not possible). So on specific dates this error would pop-up. How do you suggest to overcome this?

Comment: What output do you actually want here?  E.g. the 31st would cause problems for half the year.  What day should be displayed?

Comment: For anything but the simplest arithmetic with dates, it is best to use a pre-engineered date table. Even once you have that, where the date cycle in question is "ragged" (has a varying number of days), you have to include logic to determine how the months which don't contain certain days are handled. For example, for the 29th Feb on non-leap years, do you select 28th Feb, 1st Mar, or ignore it altogether?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Apologies Tim, I have edited the question, to make the requirement more clear, as date is not required to be displayed in the output  it can be in the format 'mon-yy'

Comment: It's the ANSI standard: http://oracle-wtf.blogspot.co.uk/2006/02/stop-press-oracle-granted-license-to.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC of a date literal is *stupid*, but I left it as you'd have SYSDATE anyway, wouldn't you?):

```
SQL> select to_char(add_months(trunc(date '2017-12-29'), -level), 'dd-mon-yy',
  2                 'nls_Date_language = english') as month
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 12;

MONTH
------------------
29-nov-17
29-oct-17
29-sep-17
29-aug-17
29-jul-17
29-jun-17
29-may-17
29-apr-17
29-mar-17
28-feb-17
29-jan-17
29-dec-16

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: The potential problem with this approach is that 28th Feb is selected for up to 4 given days of the month (28,29,30,31). There are few real-world contexts where that is desirable behaviour.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the "problem", that's how Oracle subtracts months from dates. Could you - in some more details - explain what problem you are trying to solve, so that someone might provide a *better* solution? For example, if "sysdate" was Dec 31: what date in February do you expect? My query returns Feb 28 and - as you said that it is *wrong* result, what date would be correct, then?

Comment: I'm not the OP - I'm not saying your answer is wrong, I'm only pointing out that it can't be assumed that it is the right approach to address the underlying problem or requirement (about which the OP has said nothing).

Comment: LOL! I apologize, Steve; didn't pay enough attention to who said what. Sorry.

Comment: Apologies @Littlefoot , format of the MONTH column should be 'mon-yy'

Comment: So, remove "DD-" from format mask; you should be able to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior of `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH` is as documented, see [Datetime/Interval Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#sthref135)

You should consider function [ADD_MONTHS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions011.htm#SQLRF00603):

> If date is the last day of the month or if the resulting month has
>   fewer days than the day component of date, then the result is the last
>   day of the resulting month. Otherwise, the result has the same day
>   component as date.

It depends on your requirements what you consider as "right". In fact "one month" does not have a fixed duration.

Comment: Yes, this is helpful too